# jQuery replacing data with data from a url

Tags: jquery

How can I replace the current content with data from a url? Would I be able to replaceWith() a load()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.replaceWith()` at all. `.load()` is sufficient.

```
$('#foo').load('/bar');
```

replaces the contents of element with ID `foo` with the HTML at `/bar`.

Comment: Will it replace the content that is already loaded though?

Comment: I feel dumb. I'm sorry. How do I delete this question?

Comment: Click "delete" below the tags on your post.

Comment: Hmm, says I can't delete. Thanks though for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function. When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus
>   is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data. This means that most uses of the
>   method can be quite simple:

```
$('#elementToLoadInto').load('path/contentToLoad.html');
```

And yes, it will replace the content already in the selected element.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure about that. thanks.